# Code causing formula not to work properly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

I have a worksheet named data and several worksheets in the same workbook that are staff names.

The data worksheet contains the summary of the individual staff worksheets.

On the data worksheet column A is the workers name, Column B is tasks assigned in last 30 days, Column C is tasks assigned in last 7 days, Column D is Date/Time last 1 hour task assigned and Column E is Date/Time last task was assigned.

In the individual staff worksheets, the following code allows when something is typed in column B, the date and time is automatically entered in column E.

**Here is the code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Columns("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = Format(Now, "mm dd yyyy h:mm")
    End If
End Sub
```

My problem is that since I have entered that code, the information on the data sheet in columns B,C, D and E are incorrect.

It isn't counting the information on the individual staff sheets.

The formulas were working before I added the code.

For example - Amy had 3 reports in the last 30 days prior to me adding the code.

Since adding the code, she has received 4 more reports.

Column B on the data sheet should say 7, however it still shows 3.

Any assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that your date/time stamps aren't being stored as real dates. Try using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Columns("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        with Target.Offset(0, 3)
          .Value = Now
          .Numberformat = "mm dd yyyy h:mm"
        end with
    End If
End Sub
```